# Grammar and accuracy

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english

I work for an ESL Teaching School and I was asked to make an application form for all students who wish to apply to study at our school.

I have some questions about the following questions I've created:

1. Identify any incorrect sentences in this list, EXPLAIN THE ERROR and SUPPLY the corrected version:
2. What is your preferred learning style?
3. Outline your reasons for wanting to learn English, what you hope to gain from it, and how it fits in with your plans for the future. (200-300 WORDS)

As far as I'm concerned, the grammar structure is fine, but I just want to know if you guys can encounter some vagueness on those sentences, any suggestions would be really appreciated,

Greetings from Mexico
Vanessa

Comment: What exactly is 'an ESL Teaching School': a school that teaches English as a second language, **or** a school that teaches how to teach English as a second language? If the former, one would need to know more about the level of proficiency in English that the candidates are expected to have at the point of applying.

Comment: This is partly on-topic here, but partly belongs on English Learners.SE.  (a) Your instruction (1) mixes plural and singular in an inventive way some would consider suboptimal. ' ... and in each case where there is an error, explain this error ...'. // (3) contains a weak use of pronouns ('it' being ... English? Your learning of it? Proficiency in English?)

Comment: Someone just down-voted both the current answers without giving any reason.  Strange.

Comment: I think you meant accuracy. But this site does not exist to review texts.

Answer (score 3):

- By "incorrect sentences", I think you mean "gramatically incorrect sentences". But some of your applicants might not realize this and will end up correcting the facts or opinions expressed in those sentences instead.
- It's not obvious why some words are SHOUTED so loudly.
  Indicating stress (change of voice changes the meaning of the sentence) and importance (spoken more slowly to ensure people hear it) by using *italic* or **bold** would be better (like `<em>` and `<strong>` in HTML.  See [HTML: The strong and em tags](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/html-the-strong-and-em-tags/5341594157056000)).
- Do the applicants have any idea what "learning style" means?  Even if they do, consider reading this debunking article: [Are ‘Learning Styles’ Real? - The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2018/04/the-myth-of-learning-styles/557687/).

UPDATE:
You might also want to consider:

- Are all the applicants at a similar age and education level?
  Some might be very literate and simply want to clean up the finer points, while others might barely know any English.
- Almost all applicants are likely to ask others for help when filling out the application.
  The answers you get won't be a measure of *their* knowledge, but of their friends and relatives.

No matter how well designed your form is, the results aren't likely to provide the reliable information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pay particular attention to Ray Butterworth. his advice is sound.

Your application form should be easy to understand, plain, clear, and have simple questions.

It is a form for those who want to learn English, not for those who are already familiar with tired educational jargon such as “learning style”.

The use of capitals adds no meaning, is unnecessary and is confusing.

“Identify, explain, supply ...” is too long a sequence of instructions for a basic learner.

The idea that errors are easily seen, easily discussed and uniquely correctable is just nonsense, as any reader of this site will know. Ask simple questions so that you give the applicant confidence to work through the form without being discouraged. In that way you will have more chance of seeing their strengths and weaknesses.